# Regarding Mono Develop Upgrade on Raspberry Pi

Tags: monodevelop, sigabrt

I have a  Winform application in C#(which executes fine on Windows) but crashes in Mono on the Raspberry Pi due to the following error.

*Assertion at mini-codegen. c:807,condition 'i==sel' not met.
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code.This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application.

After some research,I found out that the version of Mono on the Pi does not support Winform's Textbox control and hence the above error.I have Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8  (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4+rpi1) version installed on the Pi.
Seems like a later version of Mono has fixed this bug(3.8.1).

Can someone please explain how to do an upgrade of the Mono to the latest or required version.The Pi has Linux installed on it.
I have tried the following commands(sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.) but the version on the Pi still shows up as 3.2.8.

-Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are running "RASPBIAN Debian Wheezy", the latest from Mono's repo is 4.0.2 on that platform, so you need to change your apt-get sources to look at Mono's repos:

**Debian, Ubuntu, and derivatives**

Add the Mono Project GPG signing key and the package repository to your system (if you don’t use sudo, be sure to switch to root):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Run a package **upgrade** to upgrade existing packages to the latest available. Then install Mono as described in the Usage section.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Note: While the APT package is built against Debian Wheezy, it is compatible with a number of Debian derivatives (including Ubuntu) which means you can use the same repository across all these distributions.

From : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives